# changing existing data in viewcontroller between view controllers with self.dismiss

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I have a view controller. That does a `Modal present Segue` of a full screen view controller. It passes the image data list to the full screen view controller. This list has properties associated with it such as likes, views, etc. I have looked at ther answers, but believe they will completely replace the current array, which I think will completely reload every bit of data that is cashed on the first view. So I only want to modify data that needs to be modified.

```
Class FirstController {
    var photosList: [customStruct] = [Photo1,Photo2,Photo3] 
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "photofull" {

        if let fullImaageViewController = segue.destination as? ImageDetailViewController {
            fullImageViewController.photosList = photosList
        }
    }
}
```

here the data is passed forward through a Modal view controller. In the full imageViewcontroller, the data, such as like can be altered. `[photosList[1].imageLikes = photosList[1].imageLikes+1`

The only problem I am only able to change this data on the fullImageViewController, not in the FirstController. is there a way to access it on the previous one too?

I would like to do something like `FirstController().[photosList[1].imageLikes = FirstController.photosList[1].imageLikes+1` which doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what you need here is a simple **delegate protocol** to transfer data from one `ViewController` to another `ViewController`.

Below are the steps how to work with protocol.

**In `ViewController2`** or `fullImaageViewController` do the following steps.

Just above your class declaration declare your delegate.

```
protocol MyDelegate:class { // declare your protocol a class protocol
    func sendDataBack(value: Photo)
}
```

In `class` declare a `variable` of your `delegate`

```
weak var myDelegateObj: MyDelegate? // always declare a weak delegate so that it cannot capture the memory of the object
```

and when you `dismiss the VC` just call the delegate with line

```
myDelegateObj?.sendDataBack(value: Photo)
```

---

Now go to your `FirstViewController` and go to the line where you have declared the `FirstViewController Obj` if not declare it either in `viewdidload` or when you `presenting` your view.
 and do the following.

```
let vc = FirstViewController()
vc.myDelegateObj = self
```

and implement the method your delegate in the `FirstViewController`

**In FirstViewController:**

> ```
> make your firstView conform to MyDelegate Protocol by doing:
> ```

`class FirstViewController: UIViewController,MyDelegate`

> and Implement the MyDelegate Method

```
// update only altered photo
func sendDataBack(value: Photo) {
    if let index = photosList.index(where: {$0.imageID == Photo.imageID}){
        PhotoList[index] = Photo
    }
 }
```

And then before the initial segue, I use

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "photofull" {
        if let fullImaageViewController = segue.destination as? ViewController2 {
            fullImaageViewController.myDelegateObj = self
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: do accept the answer if it was helpful to you anyway, thanks in advance :)

Comment: rather than doing this  `fullImaageViewController.myDelegateObj = self as! MyDelegate`,  just make your view controller conform to `MyDelegate` by doing this `class ViewController: UIViewController, MyDelegate `, 

then you just need to do `fullImaageViewController.myDelegateObj = self`

Answer (score 0):

On your `fullImaageViewController` create a protocol. And assign that protocol (delegate) to `FirstViewController`.

Then call protocol function in `FullImaageViewController` with needed information to make required update in `FirstViewController`.

Think mail composer `delegate` functions.